# How to set the timeout time for the invoke method in appfabric

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

Sometimes we are experimenting this timeoutexception:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465932.aspx

Someone knows where can I set the timeout parameter for WorkflowInvoker.Invoke in appfabric? Is this possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AppFabric and IIS to host your workflows I am assuming you are using workflow services. In that case you are not using the WorkflowInvoker but the WorkflowServiceHost to run your workflows.

Comment: Are you sure? I suppose so for the call to the "wcf" service operation, but when a service gets, for instance, into a delay and it restarts... still does it use it the WorkflowServiceHost? If so, does it have a timeout property?

Comment: Yes I am sure :-) The WSH has no timeout for running a workflow, that can take as long as needed. There are several timeouts, like the SendTimeout, in the WCF stack for how long the processing of an individual message can take though. Maybe you should update your question with what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve.